# How can I put a image as backgroud to all XIB's in my app as a common method?

Tags: ios, swift, function, uiimageview, xib

I want to put background image to all XIB's in my app but I dont want to take imageview in my all XIB's.

I want to make a common method where I can take only single imageView and single outlet which can effect in all my XIB's and if I change that imageView's image then reflect to all XIB's too.

How Can I do that?

Please any helpful answer will be appreciated.

Comment: set your view background color as clear and set the image to your UIWindow.

Answer (score 1):

Just create `BaseViewController`  With `UIImageView` background you want

then  make all other `Viewcontroller` inherits from it

**BaseViewController:**

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // add your Image View // with all constraints
        self.view.addSubview(UIImageView())
    }

}
```

**Other ViewControllers:**

```
class ViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base controller which all other controllers inherit from but you should setup your background image and make sure to send it to the very back.

Playground code:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class BackgroundedViewController: UIViewController {
    let backgroundImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "bg"))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupBackground()
    }

    private func setupBackground() {

        view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
        backgroundImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        backgroundImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // fill the background.
        backgroundImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundImageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true

        // keep this at the very back
        backgroundImageView.layer.zPosition = -1
    }
}

class VC: BackgroundedViewController {}

let vc = VC()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```